# Increase the range of getCurrentPlace

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm playing with Google Places API for Android, i tried to retrieve location next to me with this sample :

```
PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result =
                Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                Log.d("Hello", "Got results: " + likelyPlaces.getCount() + " place found.");

                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    Log.i("Hello", String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",
                            placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                }

                likelyPlaces.release();
            }
        });
```

The problem is that it returns only places really next to me, is there a way to increase the range of the places returned by this function ?

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the call is to get the place that the device is currently located at. The only reason it returns a list is because it can't necessarily tell for sure which of the places listed you are currently at. It's not meant to be used for seeing nearby places in a broader sense.

If you want to see what is around you, rather than the exact place you are at, the API does include a handy UI component for that. It is called the [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont want that the user manage something with Places. I dont need any UI.